# How to create a new column from existing column?

Tags: sql, teradata

In a table AZ I have 3 columns say a,b,c || here c is alias of d || how to create a new column in same table say "e" from column c

```
select 
    a.lyl_id_no,
    sum(a.trn_tot_prc) as PURCH,
    sum(case when a.trn_dt > current_date - 365 then 1 else 0 end) cnt_trips_1yr , 
from abc a
group by 1
```

result :

```
a.lylid   purch  cnt_trips_lyr
123        12          4
242        10         1
```

But I need a new column in same table where it should say cnt_trips_1yr > 3 , cnt_trips_1yr > 2

Comment: the question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, just add more conditions.  I think the easiest way is to use a subquery:

```
select a.*,
       (case when cnt_trips_1yr > 3 then 1 else 0 end) as IsCntGt3,
       (case when cnt_trips_1yr > 2 then 1 else 0 end) as IsCntGt2
from (select a.lyl_id_no,
             sum(a.trn_tot_prc) as PURCH,
             sum(case when a.trn_dt > current_date - 365 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_trips_1yr
      from abc a
      group by a.lyl_id_no
     ) a;
```